# How do I tape new drywall that is butted up against a textured wall?

Tags: drywall, texture, taping

I'm replacing the bottom 12" of Sheetrock after water damage. The existing drywall is textured. How do I tape it? Do I have to sand off texture for  6" and then tape it and texture?

Comment: this sounds like a repeat question.

Answer (score 3):

Scraping then taping will work.  Re-blending the new and old textures invisibly is nearly impossible.

Consider replacing 3 to 4ft instead of 12" and adding a wainscot or just a chair rail and leave the bottom smooth.

Answer (score 0):

after you replace the drywall you can probably wet the texture area soft enough to scrape, If that don't work then you will need to sand. Make sure you take off enough texture about 15'above the crack. After you tape you will need to float the joint, I would float from the floor all the way were the texture starts up smooth it out cut the top edge off the joint compound  with your finishing knife, Final coat will be skimming the repair out sand then retexture.